# Error while create Progress Dialog on Database create

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I would like to implement a progress dialog when the database load the data for the first time.

this is my code

```
      DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(ENG_FRA_TABLE_CREATE);
            loadDictionaryEngFra();
            new InitDB().execute();


    }


    public class InitDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mHelperContext, "", "Wait", true);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

If i try to run the app with this progress dialog, it throw this error list

```
04-18 23:16:30.886: E/SQLiteLog(26059): (1) no such table: ENG_FRAdictionary
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059): Error inserting suggest_text_1=abbey suggest_text_2=n. a monastery ruled by an abbot
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ENG_FRAdictionary (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO ENG_FRAdictionary(suggest_text_1,suggest_text_2) VALUES (?,?)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:686)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1573)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1445)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper.addWordEngFra(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:238)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper.loadWordsEngFra(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:218)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper.access$1(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:208)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper$1.run(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:200)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/DictionaryDatabaseEngFra(26059): unable to add word: abbey
04-18 23:16:30.896: W/dalvikvm(26059): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d24930)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-51326
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.searchtoto/databases/dictionaryEngFra
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1543)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1445)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper.addWordEngFra(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:238)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper.loadWordsEngFra(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:218)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper.access$1(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:208)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper$1.run(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:200)
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/AndroidRuntime(26059):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059): Search suggestions query threw an exception.
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:804)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:265)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper$InitDB.onPreExecute(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:174)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra$DictionaryOpenHelper.onCreate(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:162)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.query(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:113)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.getWordMatchesEngFra(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.java:96)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryProviderEngFra.getSuggestions(DictionaryProviderEngFra.java:107)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at com.example.searchtoto.dictionary.en.DictionaryProviderEngFra.query(DictionaryProviderEngFra.java:81)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:375)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:318)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.app.SearchManager.getSuggestions(SearchManager.java:930)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(SuggestionsAdapter.java:200)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:49)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 23:16:30.996: W/SuggestionsAdapter(26059):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

whitout the implementation of the progress dialog, the app run fine

this is the activity

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Contains logic to return specific words from the dictionary, and
 * load the dictionary table when it needs to be created.
 */
public class DictionaryDatabaseEngFra extends SearchableDictionaryEngFra{
private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabaseEngFra";

//The columns we'll include in the dictionary table
public static final String KEY_WORD_ENG_FRA = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION_ENG_FRA = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionaryEngFra";
private static final String ENG_FRA_TABLE = "ENG_FRAdictionary";


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMapEngFra = buildColumnMapEngFra();

static File ENG_FRA = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/dic/dictionary/engfra./", "eng_fra.txt");



/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context The Context within which to work, used to create the DB
 */
public DictionaryDatabaseEngFra(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Builds a map for all columns that may be requested, which will be given to the 
 * SQLiteQueryBuilder. This is a good way to define aliases for column names, but must include 
 * all columns, even if the value is the key. This allows the ContentProvider to request
 * columns w/o the need to know real column names and create the alias itself.
 */
private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMapEngFra() {
    HashMap<String,String> mapEngFra = new HashMap<String,String>();
    mapEngFra.put(KEY_WORD_ENG_FRA, KEY_WORD_ENG_FRA);
    mapEngFra.put(KEY_DEFINITION_ENG_FRA, KEY_DEFINITION_ENG_FRA);
    mapEngFra.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
            BaseColumns._ID);
    mapEngFra.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
    mapEngFra.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
    return mapEngFra;
}

public Cursor getWordEngFra(String rowId, String[] columns) {
    String selection = "rowid = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

}


public Cursor getWordMatchesEngFra(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD_ENG_FRA + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}


private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
    /* The SQLiteBuilder provides a map for all possible columns requested to
     * actual columns in the database, creating a simple column alias mechanism
     * by which the ContentProvider does not need to know the real column names
     */
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(ENG_FRA_TABLE);



    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMapEngFra);


    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}


/**
 * This creates/opens the database.
 */
private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    /* Note that FTS3 does not support column constraints and thus, you cannot
     * declare a primary key. However, "rowid" is automatically used as a unique
     * identifier, so when making requests, we will use "_id" as an alias for "rowid"
     */



    private static final String ENG_FRA_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + ENG_FRA_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                KEY_WORD_ENG_FRA + ", " +
                KEY_DEFINITION_ENG_FRA + ");";



    DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(ENG_FRA_TABLE_CREATE);
            loadDictionaryEngFra();
            new InitDB().execute(); 
    }


    public class InitDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mHelperContext, "", "Wait", true);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts a thread to load the database table with words
     */
    private void loadDictionaryEngFra() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWordsEngFra();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loadWordsEngFra() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words eng_fra...");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ENG_FRA);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWordEngFra(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }

    /**
     * Add a word to the dictionary.
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long addWordEngFra(String word, String definition) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WORD_ENG_FRA, word);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION_ENG_FRA, definition);

        return mDatabase.insert(ENG_FRA_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }



    /**
     * Add a word to the dictionary.
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ENG_FRA_TABLE);

        onCreate(db);

    }


}

}
```

Comment: there is a problem in your sqlite helper. you should post the full code for dbhelper class.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an SQL error.

```
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059): Error inserting suggest_text_1=abbey suggest_text_2=n. a monastery ruled by an abbot
04-18 23:16:30.896: E/SQLiteDatabase(26059): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ENG_FRAdictionary (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO ENG_FRAdictionary(suggest_text_1,suggest_text_2) VALUES (?,?)
```

It doesn't look like your ENG_FRAdictionary table exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your sqlite db. I can't see a problem with progress dialog
Check your db creation statement and table names. Also check the sqlitehelper class
And let us know what happens

Comment: This error happen just if i implement the progress dialog, without it, the database doesn't give me any error

Comment: Because you are giving invalid context
ProgressDialog.show(mHelperContext, "", "Wait", true);
mHelperCOntext is defined for dictionary helper(I know it is final)
can you try to send it to the asynctask.. and It has to be an activity context not application context

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem is if i try to set pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DictionaryDatabaseEngFra.this, "", "Wait", true); i receive an error No enclosing instance of the type DictionaryDatabaseEngFra is accessible in scope